# Remesh at low values shatters model into fractures

Tags: modeling

When I remesh at low values such as `0.01m` or `0.005m` I get the following shattered result. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looks like it because your mesh is not closed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I exported a character from DAZ Studio and I wanted to use the Remesh modifier in Blender to optimize its 3D print. Blender removed the head when using the modifier :) Thanks to your reply, I learnt it was because the eyes of the model (Genesis 9) are not closed, so I closed them and it worked perfectly :)